# Helm _helpers.yaml template with bool returning %!S(Bool=True) instead of string

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I have the following Helm template definition:

```yaml
{{- define "api.test-drive" -}}
{{- if not .Values.global.testDrive }}
{{- printf "%s" .Values.default.TEST_DRIVE | quote -}}
{{- else -}}
{{- printf "%s" .Values.global.testDrive | title | quote -}}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

With the following in a configmap template:

```
TEST_DRIVE: {{ include "api.test-drive" . }}
```

And a global value of `global.testDrive: true`. However, when Helm executes this an inserts into the configmap, it is storing it as:

```
TEST_DRIVE:
----
%!S(Bool=True)
```

Shouldn't the printf be casting `global.testDrive` from a bool `true` to a string then applying the `title` and `quote` function? It is not clear what is happening here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Go [`text/template`](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template) `printf` template function passes through directly to `fmt.Printf()`, but the [`fmt`](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt) package defines its format strings a little bit differently from C's **printf**(3) function.  In particular, the `%s` format modifier is only defined for string-type arguments, and you've passed it a bool-type argument; the `%!s(...)` output means there was an error processing a `%s` argument (see [Format errors](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#hdr-Format_errors)).

If you want to use `printf` here, `%v` will convert an arbitrary value to a string with a default syntax

```
{{- printf "%v" .Values.global.testDrive | title | quote -}}
{{/*        ^^                                          */}}
```

Helm includes [a generic `toString` helper](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#type-conversion-functions) which might be more convenient here.

```
{{- .Values.global.testDrive | toString | title | quote -}}
```

(...but [under the hood](https://github.com/Masterminds/sprig/blob/master/strings.go#L174-L187) in most cases `toString` does the equivalent of `printf "%v"`.)